# How to implement e2e testing in Nest JS Framework

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-config, nestjs-passport

I am new this Framework. I implemented crud operation, migration, unit testing also but I do know how to implement e2e testing in nest JS Framework. I tried to run the e2e testing program it's throwing an error
How to fix this error. I tried many ways but I could not get the solution
[image]It showing this error **No repository for "UserEntity" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?**. So, I tried to change my database configuration

**Database configuration**

```
{
              type: 'postgres',
              host:  process.env[`${process.env.NODE_ENV}_POSTGRES_HOST`],
              port: parseInt(process.env[`${process.env.NODE_ENV}_POSTGRES_PORT`]) || 5432,
              username: process.env[`${process.env.NODE_ENV}_POSTGRES_USER`],
              password: process.env[`${process.env.NODE_ENV}_POSTGRES_PASSWORD`],
              database: process.env[`${process.env.NODE_ENV}_POSTGRES_DATABASE`],
              entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{ .ts,.js}"],
              migrations: ["dist/database/migration/*.js"],
              cli:{
                  migrationsDir: 'src/database/migration',
                  }
            }
```

This problem is occurred in the **entities column** in the database configuration. If I change the entities directory the application cannot run. how to fix this issue

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

Comment: what if you change `dist` to `src` in your database config? Also, show us how is your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: @ Micael Levi If I change dist to src they application won's run. it's showing same error.

Comment: can u please edit your question to add the `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @ Micael Levi can you please check it again I edited the question

Comment: it think its right. Are you sure that your database config is loaded? also, idk if you already saw this repo: https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs

Comment: Yes when i run e2e testing code it's showing this error. It's any alternative way for config entitles(different path).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230874/discussion-between-hariprasath-vengatachalam-and-micael-levi).

Answer (score 2):

e2e is basically a test where the client is talking to the controller.

"UserEntity" most of the times should never see the light of day.
Instead, a userDto could become the front object which will then parse its values in the userEntity.

With that said, let's discuss more of what *should* happen.

1. The e2e test sends a get request to the controller
2. The function inside the controller with the @Get() decorator receives the request

*example*

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
 @Get() 
  public async helloWorld(){
    //// does something
  }
}
```

3. Then, the function calls the service where the crud is implemented

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
    @Get() 
    public helloWorld(){
      return this.userService.get();
    }
}
```

4. To be able to call the service from the controller, you are going to need a constructor.

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
 constructor(private readonly userService: UserService){}

    @Get() 
    public helloWorld(){
      return this.userService.get();
    }
}
```

All these files, must be included in the app.module.

- The service as a provider
- The controller as a controller
- And everything database-related must be imported

*example*

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UserEntiy,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now, in the test file you should import the AppModule so the project can start and your controller is up and waiting to recieve http requests.

If your paths in db config are looking at dist, make sure you run
`npm run build` after changes